# Inserting JSON string into MySQL column UTF-8

Tags: mysql, json, post, utf-8

I am generating **JSON valid string** like: `[{"head":"Model Name","body":"T102HA-GR015T"}]`

The string generated on ***UTF-8*** page with `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and file encoding ***UTF-8***.

The connection to database made by PDO with `charset=utf8`

DB table & column collations are `utf8_general_ci`

**When it inserted to db it look like:**

*For Russian*: `[{"head":"\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043c\u043e\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0438","body":"T102HA-GR015T"}]`

*For Hebrew*: `[{"head":"\u05d3\u05d2\u05dd","body":"T102HA-GR015T"}]`

**And I want it to be inserted to db in actual lang characters, like:**

*For Russian*: `[{"head":"Название модели","body":"T102HA-GR015T"}]`

*For Hebrew*: `[{"head":"דגם","body":"T102HA-GR015T"}]`

**phpMyAdmin screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Something (other than MySQL) is encoding it...  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/617/json/2019/encoding-a-json-string#t=201612301618432725187

Comment: @RickJames thanks a lot, it helped me to resolve it with `$array = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @RickJames for helping, solved using **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**

`$array = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`